# Найти n непересекающихся массивов суммарной минимальной длины

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм, поиск

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть отсортированный набор массивов(примерно 200)
Необходимо найти n массивов(n дано), что эти массивы не будут иметь общих элементов и суммарная длина этих массивов минимальная(то есть среди этого множества массивов нельзя найти n таких массивов, что их длина будет меньше)
Если найти n массивов нельзя, уведомить об этом
Пытался брать сначала первый массив, потом все возможные варианты(то есть второй массив и все возможные варианты, потом третий и т.д.)
И также записывать длину и кол-во, чтобы  найти самый короткий, но состоящий из n
Но он перебирает не все варианты, выдает массивы большей длины

Comment: Похоже на [задачу о клике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5). Уточните ограничения на длину массивов и на значения элементов. Объясните что означает «отсортированный набор массивов». Ну, и если это задача с какого-то сайта, то дайте ссылку.

Comment: Длина каждого массива известна
Максимальная длина 1000
Значения инт, значения элементов от нуля до известной величины(примерно 5000), то есть легко хешируется
Сами массивы отсортированы по возрастанию, массивы хранятся в виде списков и списки отсортированы по длине массива

Comment: Я сначала думал брать наименьший по размеру массив и находить остальные массивы без дубликатов(записывая уникальные значения всех массивов в ассоциативный массив)
Но может так получиться, что из-за наименьшего массива  будут пропущены еще два или более массивов
Если упростить задачу, то её можно сформулировать так:
Найти найти наибольшее количество массивов без дубликатов

Comment: "Если упростить задачу" - так может, задача вообще по-другому формулируется? Дал обзорный ответ, чтобы была возможность продолжить, если закроют.

Comment: Нет, я именно упростил
Я решил, что если дадут подсказку, как решить более легкую, то сложную я смогу решить по аналогии

Answer (score 3):

Это разновидность [задачи о независимом множестве вершин](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5) - для построения графа нужно соединить рёбрами массивы с пересечениями. Проблема двойственна (задаётся на дополнении графа - т.е. рёбра соединяют непересекающиеся массивы) задаче [о клик](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5)е, которую уже упомянул @default locale. Возможно, будет проще решать тот вариант, где меньше рёбер (или наоборот ;))

Существование упомянутого в в вопросе ограничения в n массивов определяется [хроматическим числом графа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE).

В данном случае нужно найти независимое множество с наименьшим весом (общей длиной массивов). Вкупе с ограничением на число вершин задача может усложниться (в частности, при использовании приближённых, эвристических методов), однако она в любом случае NP-hard и, скорее всего, придётся перебирать все комбинации.